# Angular post request to NodeJS JSON error

Tags: node.js, json, angular, post

So i am sending a POST request to a nodeJS app, my request in Angular looks like this:

```
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  newWord = '';
  keyword = '';

  onClick() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:3000/search', JSON.stringify(this.keyword), {
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: headers,
      })
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.newWord = data;
      });
  }
}
```

When i try to console.log the request i get an Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0 error even though i tried all the solutions i could find on stackoverflow this is how my NodeJS app is set and the error:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With"
  );
  next();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});

app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.body);  
});
```

The error i get is this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)....
```

Note that the this.keyword gets its value from a input field if i dont use JSON.stringify no error is happening but the req variable is "undefined".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking how to get back the data. I'm not sure if this will work, but you can give it a try:

Under comments, see that you mean this.keyword. Here is the change I would make

going by axis format, this may be incorrect

```
.post('http://localhost:3000/search', JSON.stringify(this.keyword), {
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: headers,
      })
```

instead, try:

```
.post('http://localhost:3000/search', {
        keyword: this.keyword, // changed this
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: headers,
      })
```

also in your server, you can change to this:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.text())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

(body parser included in express now)

new to the mern stack (have never used Angular) so kind of iffy but hopefully that can help

Comment: Well i am asking how to get the data (the this.keyword basically) to the NodeJS app. What i want to build is an input that when the button is clicked it sends the data to the nodeJS app and then it returns some data based on the input by the user

Comment: I tried what you suggested unfortunatelly it doesnt work still get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError

Comment: And how is the post request you suggested sending the this.keyword sorry iam very new and kinda confused.

Comment: I just found out that this propably causes a problem

Comment: `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: Oh, didn't realize you wanted to send this.keyword until your first comment to this. That being said, I will edit the answer.

Comment: well if anything helps when i remove the `app.use(express.json())` everything works but the `req` variable is just empty brackets and req.body is undefined.

Comment: No! Definitely use app.use(express.json()). Otherwise, you will have no body in your post when using json format as you are in the example. I edited it, try it now.

Comment: Well it worked now passing the this.keyword variable as you suggested solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Was stuck on an express problem for past 4 days until I solved using api documentation, it can definitely be a pain lol.

Comment: well now i am stuck in another problem but thats something i will need to work on. Have a great rest of the day!